# How to change root directory from different device (e.g. /dev/sdb1 to /dev/sda2)

Tags: boot, root, devices, fdisk

I have an Ubuntu when booted it has the root system is 
stored under `/dev/sdb1`, as can be shown with `df` command:

[image]

the `fdisk -l` looks like this:

[image]

My question is how can I change the root system from `/dev/sdb1` 
to `/dev/sda2`? And when boot also goes to `/dev/sda2`

Comment: In other words you want the otjher device `/dev/sda2` to boot rathan the current one or you want to move the OS from `/dev/sdb1` to the new location?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen That's right!

Comment: bro please be very clear what you want, to move the current OS to a new location or ask the system to boot from else where?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Sorry, I don't see the difference. I  want `/dev/sda2` to be the main place to work: boot, OS?, place where installed app resides (e.g Apache, MySQL), home directory, etc.

Comment: Why exactly do you want this? It may be possible in theory, but one mistake and you will mess up your machine big time.

Comment: There is a huge difference if OS is on `/dev/sdb1`, moving will involve cloning but if another OS is on `/dev/sda2` then you simple change the entries in the `/etc/fstab` to point to that location. There is a huge difference make sure you know what you want and what your doing else!

Comment: @Jos Thanks. I want to install a local web server (UCSC Genome Browser) that require a large disk space (10TB) to store some data. To do that these servers need Apache and MySQL. Please advice if you have better suggestion.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Thanks. How can I check if `/dev/sda2` contains OS or not?

Comment: Leave your root partition where it is (as long as it is large enough to fit the software) and store your data on an external disk. That is very easy.

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalling the OS on `sda` would be the safe way, but isn't really needed. Since you have a filesystem on `sda2`, either:

- if you can use it entirely for you data, create a mount point on your `sdb1` filesystem here you want the data, and mount it there (add to `/etc/fstab`).
- otherwise, mount it (under root or else, still by adding to `/etc/fstab`), create a directory in it for your data, and create a soft link to it from where you want need your data to be.

Answer (score 1):

To change mount points, we must edit the fstab file (see link above), so let's open it and have it fork to the background with the & symbol. For Ubuntu, open a terminal and run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab &
```

Locate the entry you want to change. Let's say you discover that the device is /dev/sdb1. Then you will change the line in fstab from something like

```
/dev/sdb1       /media/disk2    ext3    defaults,errors=remount-ro  0  2
```

to

```
/dev/sdb1       /mnt/backup     ext3    defaults,errors=remount-ro  0  2
```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MoveMountpointHowto

Comment: does this method also boots on `/dev/sda2` ? I want all the software (e.g. Apache, MySql, etc to be installed in `/dev/sda2` ). In short to use  `/dev/sda2` it as main device.